# Making multiple async calls to web service

Tags: objective-c, json, design-patterns, asynchronous

I need to be able to make multiple json post calls to a web service. Code wise I know how to do this I'm just looking for opinions/suggestions on this logic. I am taking Core Data objects and sending them back to a web service:

```
- (void) startSaveProcess  { 

    if (self.arrWithObjectsToSave.count > 0) { 

         //convert CD obj to NSData

        [self postJSON:NSData:CD Object];

   } else { 

       //do post save stuff
   }

} 

- (void) postJSON : (NSData*) data : (PA*) thisPA { 

     //NSURL async call with completion block...

    //success
    if (data.length && responseError == nil) { 
        //do some post save house cleaning on thisPA

        [self.arrWithObjectsToSave removeObject:thisPA];

        [self startSaveProcess];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using AFNetworking or RestKit which both offer queue management for a number of pending requests (band RestKit offers mapping which would abstract you away from JSON serialisation).

Specifically, using the operation queue of the http client (depending on the version used).